# powershell script and subst command

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following powershell 2.0 script:

```
function getFreeDrive
{
    [char[]]$driveLetters = @([char]'E'..[char]'Z')
    foreach ($d in $driveLetters) {
        if(!(Test-Path -Path "$d`:" -IsValid)) {
            return $d
        }
    }
}

$drive = getFreeDrive

subst "$drive`:" T:\temp 
ls "$drive`:\"  # just a dummy command 
subst "$drive`:" /D
```

I want the script to

- find the first unused drive letter
- create a new drive with subst
- do something on this drive
- remove the drive with subst

The script works fine, when I run it the first time. 
If I run the script a second time in the same shell, I get an error from the **ls** command saying that the drive can not be found. If I open a new shell and run the script, it runs fine again.

What is the problem with my script and how can I get the it to run multiple times in the same powershell instance?

Or maybe there is an alternative to the **subst** command? I tried using a powershell drive, but it doesn't work with other windows programs (e.g. devenv.exe).

Comment: It works fine for me, check if the first SUBST returns any error. If it can't mount the drive then ls will fail...

Comment: @Adriano I don't get any errors. Can you run it multiple times in one shell?

Comment: Yes...it works straight.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't work for, when I run the script. When I enter the subst commands by hand, I can do it multiple times without any problems. Thanks for trying it.

Comment: For Get-FreeDrive, you could also use `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate the exact same behaviour as you, even to the point where in one Powershell window I can't even cd to the drive it's created, but if I open a brand new window I can cd to it just fine.

Behaviour seems like that outlined here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/2e414f3c-98dd-4d8b-a3a3-88cfa0e7594c/

Workaround is probably to use PSDrives as mentioned above, or just don't map, then unmap, then try to remap the same drive in the same session.

Comment: I found a bug report and voted for it: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/719412/error-mounting-and-unmounting-using-subst-and-net-use

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is using PSProviders and more accuratly PSDrives (have a look to [get-help about_providers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847791.aspx)) :

```
PS > New-PSDrive -Name "tr" -PSProvider filesystem -Root "c:\temp"

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
tr                               28,15 FileSystem    C:\temp

PS > ls tr:*.c

    Répertoire : C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        01/08/2012     05:28        994 test.c


PS > Remove-PSDrive -Name "tr"
```

The trouble is that these drives can't be used with the shell explorer.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't use a PSDrive because I need to use the drive with Visual Studio.

Comment: You can also use PowerShell in VS.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same issue, and my workaround - note I am using version 3 - is to call `Get-PSDrive` before going into newly mapped drive:

```
$drive = getFreeDrive

subst "$drive`:" T:\temp 
Get-PSDrive | Out-Null
ls "$drive`:\"  # just a dummy command 
subst "$drive`:" /D
```

Comment: Note that this actually helps when you have to use SUBST (e.g. preventing 260-char-limit).